# FullCalendar "cannot read property 'getDay' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, rendering, fullcalendar

I am using the script below to load my calendar events. Oddly enough, sometimes it seems tom load fine, other times it doesn't want to load at all. If it makes any difference, this is being loaded in jquery modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* $('.calMessagesBG').click(function(){
        $('.calMessagesContainer').fadeOut(750);
        $('.calMessagesBG').fadeOut(1250);
    }); */
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    <?php //Extend the date object (not part of fullcalendar) ?>
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
        return this;
    };<?php //end of extension ?>
    var earliestDate = new Date(); <?php // the earliest date that a package can be created ?>
    earliestDate.addDays(0);
    <?php //earliestDate.setHours(23,59,59);  //This sets the time to 11:59:59 PM - this is our way of expressing the end of the earliest day to creat booking ?> 

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height:400,
    //configure options for the calendar
       header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },
       // this is where you specify where to pull the events from.
       events: "/events/byID/25", 
       editable: false,
       defaultView: 'month',
       allDayDefault: false,
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool){
                $('.calMessages').html('<p style="width:300px">Collecting packages & booking info...</p>');
                $('.calMessagesBG').fadeIn(750);
                $('.calMessagesContainer').fadeIn(1250);
            } else {
                $('.calMessagesContainer').fadeOut(150);
                $('.calMessagesBG').fadeOut(500);
            }
        }, 
        allDaySlot: false, 
   });

});
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
 XHR finished loading: GET "http://itrekkers.com/events/byID/25?start=NaN&end=NaN&_=1400518976875". jquery-1.10.2.js:6
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDay' of undefined
```

Sample of result data:

```
 [{"id":"$2y$10$.UNkHkjRq91fd5ibB9x23.9G9ZB3lcz5B1RGb\/tbSQt85BYxYjOt6","title":"Two hour ocean experience","color":"#2798CF","textColor":"#ffffff","start":"2014-05-04 20:00:00","end":"2014-05-04 22:00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was happening because the fullCalendar object wasn't ready yet. Try to use the fullCalendar methods only after it has been fully built.